# How to redirect to a page with a special character

Tags: angularjs-scope, protractor

I have a configuration file that redirects the user to a new page after login much like [an example on github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js#L5).  The problem is that I use a `#` in my url:

```
  browser.driver.wait(function() {
      return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        return /#/home/.test(url);
      });
    }, 10000);
```

I tried escaping the `#` with html code `/&#35;`.  I also tried `//`, but then the code was treated as a comment.  I do not know how to read the line:

`return /#/home/.test(url);`

Is this a literal string calling an extension method of sorts `test(url)`?  If I knew that perhaps I could figure out what to do here.

How do I escape the character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to escape the slashes:

```
var urlChanged = function() {
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        return /\/#\/home\//.test(url);
    });
};
browser.driver.wait(urlChanged, 10000);
```

You can also just test for the `/home/` in the url:

```
return url.indexOf("/home/") > -1;
```